# Is this relation between $ \sigma( T)$ and $\sigma( e^{iT})$ true?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that $T$ is a bounded operator on some banach space $X$. We can define $e^T=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty T^n/n!$ which converges, since $T$ is bounded.

Is It true that if $\alpha\in\sigma (T)$ then $e^\alpha\in \sigma(e^T)$?

I managed to show that if $T-\alpha I$ is not injective then $e^T-e^\alpha I$ is not injective. But I was not able to show that if $T-\alpha I$ is not surjective then $e^T-e^\alpha I$ is not surjective. (Although I did manage to prove It when $ e^x$ is changed for a polynomial $P(X)$).

I also managed to solve It when we changed $T$ for an arbitrary element of a commutative  banach álgebra. Since we can find a complez homomorfism such that $f(T)=\alpha$, and since complex homomorfism are continuous It follows that $f(e^T)=e^\alpha$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\sigma(T)$?

Comment: It follows from the spectral mapping theorem for the [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus).

Comment: You can apply the Banach algebra result to the algebra generated by $T$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael could you go a little bit more into detail please?

Comment: @TrialAndError but how do you know it's commutative?

Comment: As for commutativity: $f(T) g(T) = g(T) f(T)$ because the functional calculus is an algebra homomorphism.

Comment: The spectral mapping theorem says $\sigma(f(T)) = f(\sigma(T))$ for any function $f$ analytic in a neighbourhood of $\sigma(T)$.

Comment: well crap :(${}{}{}{}$, I hope my T.A has mercy on my soul. Thanks a lot.